# Simple method of securing by php API

Tags: php, rest, authentication

I'm a front end developer by trade, but one of my apps has required a php backend api. I need to protect my API against unauthorised use, so I've created a solution which works (great!). However I'm worried I've left a gaping hole in my security and would like a second opinion. I'm pretty new to php and authorisation in general. My code is pretty convoluted so rather than posting it here, i've listed the steps below:

1) Client sends a post request from the front end with a username key, a password key, and the data for the api.

2) php backend picks this up and checks if a user exists within a SQL database.

3) if a user exists php backend hashes the posted password and checks it against the hash stored in the database.

4) if the hashes match then return API request.

I've spent weeks googling it and no one has suggested this simple method, which makes me think that I'm doing something wrong. Is there something I'm missing?

I've looked into OAuth, but it seems like overkill got my simple project,

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't have to hash, then hash again if you're using PHP's `password_hash()` - so something sounds off in the PHP API. Other than that your method sounds good enough.

Comment: Sending the username and password with every request isn't great. From your description it also sounds like you would store the user's username and password inside your JS in plaintext, also not great.

Comment: I thing. You should use token system for this.

Comment: I think you can use the JWT token based authentication

Comment: use sessions. it's classic. but if this API is going to be consumed by any other client other than browser. try using JWT tokens.